# Why python metaclass do not need to be initialized?

Tags: python

```py
class Meta(type):
    def store(self):
        print("Meta store")


class Handler(metaclass=Meta):
    pass
```

For example, we have 2 above classes.

As you know, `Meta` inherit `type` for metaclass.

```py
handler = Handler # without initialize
handler.store()
```

In this case, we can access `Meta`'s `store()` method without initializing class. (handler = Handler)

How can it happen in metaclass?

Is there any documentation detailing the inner workings of metaclasses?

Thanks.

Comment: You *did* instantiate `Meta`. `Handler` is the instance you created.

Comment: @user2357112 Where do I instantiate Meta? Can you provide more detail?

Comment: classes in Python are objects, and metaclasses are just classes of classes.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python

Comment: A class is an instance of its metaclass, so when you declare `Handler`, you are creating an instance of `Meta` named `Handler`.